# How to hide the ImageView at the end of collapsing of CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Tags: android, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I use ImageView inside CollapsingToolbarLayout and need to have control,over ImageView,hide it at the end of collapsing of CollapsingToolbarLayout and do some over ImageView,Please any ideas could help me.
There are such options

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
```

but not any options like "exitEndCollapsed".

Comment: Just up voted the question. Have you got the answer on this?

Answer (score 20):

I spent nearly two days trying to get exactly this working. I've read a lot of guides and others. now I finally resolved that! Those are steps I did:
First of all you need to move your `ImageView` in front of your Toolbar (still inside of `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Next, you have to add `app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"` into tour `CollapsingToolbarLayout` (It does that nice scrim effect at the end of scrolling.
At the end, you have to add `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` into your `Toolbar`.
And that's all... This way it worked for me. Hope it will help you.

Here is part of my activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/sceneRoot"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="168dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:text="AppBar Title"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
```

Comment: nice solution :) it save my time

Comment: Thanks, Saved my day!

Comment: It worked for me, nice solution

Answer (score 0):

In your image view just add ,

```
 app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
 app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0"
```